# How to say "The girl who likes being photographed is my friend"?

Tags: grammar

I want to say

> The girl who likes being photographed is my friend

and my attempt is as follows,

> 写真を撮って貰うことが好きだ女性は私の友達です。

Is my attempt correct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> The girl who likes being photographed is my friend.
>   写真を撮って貰うことが好き**だ**女性は私の友達です。

Change the "好きだ"(← the 終止形/predicative form) to its 連体形/attributive form "好きな" to modify the noun 女性. So your sentence would translate to:

> 写真を撮ってもらうことが好き**な**女性は私の友達です。
>   or
>   写真を撮ってもらう**の**が好きな女性は私の友達です。

You can also say it as:

> 写真に/を撮られるのが好きな女性は私の友達です。

Comment: これかな？　http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/352/glossary-simple-linguistics-terms-and-cross-reference

Comment: Both are possible (but you'd use に when you say ～～しているところを写真**に**撮られる, and を when you say 顔の写真**を**撮られる)

Answer (score 2):

撮ってもらう will give the idea that someone does the action for you.
In your case, the girl is photographed, not only because someone takes the picture for her, but also because she is the subject of the picture.
Therefore, I would rather use a passive form.

Then, you can't use 好きだ女性, 好き is a な-adjective, so it's 好きな女性.

So maybe something like this :

> [撮影]{さつえい}されるのが好きな女性は私の友達です。